# Two vcs root in teamcity and shared directory

Tags: version-control, directory, teamcity

I have two svn VCS roots (ProjectX, ProjectY). Correct build path should be:

**ParrentFolder**\ProjectX   (svn://svn_server1/ProjectX)

**ParrentFolder**\ProjectY   (svn://svn_server2/Folder1/ProjectY)

How to configure shared **ParrentFolder** for both projects? I looked into Checkout directory parameter but its seams there is no system variable which can create folder by project name.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560969/to-where-should-i-point-the-vcs-root-of-teamcity help?

Comment: @VonC I could be wrong but no

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So if anyone have similar issue you need todo next:

1. Configure checkout rule for the first project    +:.=>ProjectX
2. Configure checkout rule for the second project   +:.=>ProjectY
3. Configure correct build paths /ProjectX/ProjectX.sln, /ProjectY/ProjectY.sln

Comment: Great. I knew that had to do with "checkout rules" as I commented initially. +1

Comment: Why don't use one project as library?

Comment: Thanks for following up your question with an answer. This saved me.

Comment: Hello, could you explain step #3 - Configure correct build paths? Where in TC UI is that set?