# TeamCity 6 + Github: Configure VCS root for branches

Tags: version-control, github, continuous-integration, branch, teamcity

We're using TeamCity 6 together with Github Enterprise.
Our current project has quite a lot of branches.
The current setup of the build configurations is that we create a new VCS root for every branch.

This does not seem the way we should do it.

Is there a way we can define a single VCS root pointing to our Github repository and then configuring the for every single build?

I've seen this post: [To where should I point the VCS root of TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560969/to-where-should-i-point-the-vcs-root-of-teamcity)

But not sure whether this applies to Github as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity 7 has support for Git feature branches which will automatically build all branches matching a pattern, see the documentation for more details:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Working+with+Feature+Branches

If all you want is to have one VCS root and manually create each build configuration, you can have a single VCS root with a macro like `%BRANCH_NAME%` in the branch name field, and then in the properties of each build you just set a property with the same name to your branch name and TeamCity will find checkout the right branch.

Comment: Yes, the field is called "Ref name".

Comment: Ah ok, where would I set the properties then? Is that under Build Parameters -> System Properties?

Comment: Yes, so "Ref name" should be `%BRANCH_NAME%`. Under "6./7. Build Parameters" (it changed number in TC7), create a new "Configuration Parameter" named `BRANCH_NAME` and set its value to `your-branch-name`.